# Retrieving child ui element info from IScrollInfo

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm implementing an IScrollInfo class(ButtonPaletteScrollPanel) that goes inside of a ScrollViewer, like such:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="btnScrlVwr" CanContentScroll="True" Loaded="ScrollViewer_Loaded" Height="450">
        <vm:ButtonPaletteScrollPanel>
            <ItemsControl Name="itmCtrl" ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonList, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="blButton" 
                        Style="{StaticResource RectangularButtonStyle}" 
                                Width="950" Height="80" Margin="5"
                        Content="{Binding ButtonText}" FontSize="18"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=blGeneric, Path=DataContext.SelectionCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding TaskName}" Loaded="Button_Loaded">
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </vm:ButtonPaletteScrollPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Within my IScrollInfo class, in my MeasureOverride method, I'm trying to retrieve the height value of the button elements (i.e. 80) that are within my ButtonPaletteScrollPanel.

If I call `foreach (UIElement child in this.InternalChildren)` the child returned is my `ItemsControl`.
Can I get to my button elements from within this ItemsControl object or is there a different approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get access to your DataTemplate generated elements. This isn't too difficult to do. Here is an MSDN article that describes how:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx

Comment: Thanks this helps some, however, when I make the call to `ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) as ContentPresenter;` I'm finding that `ItemContainerGenerator` has a status of "NotStarted".  I'm trying to call this in my override of the "MeasureOverride" method.  I think I'm in a Catch-22 here as the "MeasureOverride" method is used to determine the size of the layout I need based on these button elements, however, I can't get access to these button elements until they are all loaded.

Comment: Yea what you can try for this is use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and put that code in there. Give it a priority that is lower and see if you can get it to be called after the ItemContainerGenerator has finished. If that doesn't work then you will need to subscribe to the ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged event instead.